# Django REST Framework without Auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to create a basic view using the Django REST framework without requiring authentication.

**Settings.py**

```
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
        'south',  # Database migration helpers:
        'crispy_forms',  # Form layouts
        'rest_framework',
    )

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
                'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
                    'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
                )
    }
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'ticket', views.TicketViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^test', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

)
```

**Serializers**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers

class TicketInputSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Abc
        fields = ('test')
```

**Models**

```
from django.db import models

class Abc(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

**Error**

When trying to get to the URI i get the following,

```
Page Not Found 404

Using the URLconf defined in config.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
^test ^login/$ [name='login']
^test ^logout/$ [name='logout']
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What URL do you access?

Comment: You need to go to: `<IP>/ticket/` if you want to access your API endpoint..

Comment: Thanks, however i now have another issue but ill open a new quest